# Wordpress garbled output (PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress

*Oops! Sorry, I discovered what the "bug" was, and let me just say beforehand that I apologize a lot for asking this question, the "bug" was that firebug, which I used to view the html, doesn't always seem to display the html verbatim. I'm so sorry.*

---

This shouldn't be a wordpress problem, but I can't rule out anything.  My code:

```
print "span onclick=\"replyForm(this,";

print get_the_ID();

print ",\"";

print get_comment_author();

print "\", ";

print get_comment_ID();

print ")>Reply ►/span";
```

It should output:

```
span onclick="replyForm(this,1,"name with space", 6)Reply ►/span
```

But instead it outputs:

```
span 6)="" ,="" gamer="" innate="" onclick="replyForm(this,1,">Reply ►/span
```

Even if they are separate print statements it still manages to garble it up.  Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: I don't find anything fishy with your code, it should work perfectly. What do you have before and after this code? Is there any output buffering? Or is the content being stored in some variables that are then printed/echoed? Or it might be that there are angular brackets or any other HTML character that is conflicting/breaking the SPAN tag?

Comment: If you can use ' instead of " to wrap your strings you don't have to backslash the " inside so there will be less confusion ;)

PS: why don't use a classic printf()?

Comment: See my comment to the answer below.  I was mistaken thinking firebug was showing me accurate information, but for some reason firebug showed me some garbled up junk, go figure.

Answer (score 2):

Your variables have quotes in them, so the strings are getting closed prematurely. Try using something like addslashes() or preg_replace() to make sure you don't have ' or " in your strings.

-edit Looking at it more closely, you're using " for both the onclick and to surround the string. Mix it up with a ' for one and " for the other.

Comment: But I have escaped the quotes: \"

Comment: Well, I've tried fiddling around with it, but it doesn't work and that isn't even the problem because not even the first print statement prints the string it's supposed to.

Comment: Oops!  Sorry, I discovered what the "bug" was, and let me just say beforehand that I apologize a lot for asking this question, the "bug" was that firebug, which I used to view the html, doesn't always seem to display the html verbatim.  I'm so sorry.